# How to create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) OWIN Selfhosted

Tags: owin, nancy, csr

Would I use the IIS Manager to create this CSR even though the web application is not hosted in IIS?

I have a .Net app using NancyFX that is self hosted using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting (so IIS is not used at all) and I need to create a CSR for the production server, but can't seem to find any details on how to do this.

I've tried creating the CSR using the Certificates MMC plugin, but it was rejected by the issuer due to missing Common name, Country, City/locality, Organization, State/province and an incorrect key size.

This is the first time that I need to create a CSR so I have no idea of how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate a CSR on Windows without IIS you can use OpenSSL. Download it for Windows from https://www.openssl.org/

Run the following openssl command (via run or cmd.exe)

```
openssl req -out CSR.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout private.key
```

And when you run the `openssl req` cmd, it will generate a CSR (with a *public key* embedded) and a *private key*.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @matthijsb. Can I run this on any Windows computer or do I have to run it on the server on which the certificate will be used? I won't be allowed to install OpenSSL on the production server.

Comment: No it doesn't need to happen on the same server, see http://serverfault.com/questions/471289/must-csrs-be-generated-on-the-server-that-will-host-the-ssl-certificate